# print one part of a array in double quotes

Tags: perl

What I'm trying to do is have my array names print out in a single line 
Andrew "Andy" Kaufman. This is what I have so far.

```
#DEFINE AN ARRAY
@names = (Andrew,Andy,Kaufman);

#printing the array
print "@names";
```

Comment: how do you select the name to print between quotes? is it always the 2nd element in the array?

Comment: Yes only the second one is to be in quotes. I know that I can grab each individual array by doing print @names[1] and so on.

Comment: The perlfunc man page mentions a function called printf. It'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even though Sobrique has already ansewered, another possible solution would be

```
#DEFINE AN ARRAY
my @names = qw(Andrew "Andy" Kaufman);

#printing the array
print "@names";
```

or

```
#DEFINE AN ARRAY
my @names = qw(Andrew Andy Kaufman);
#or
#my @names = ("Andrew","Andy","Kaufman");

#printing the array
print "$names[0] \"$names[1]\" $names[2]";
```

I think your main trouble was to print a double quote, you simply have to escape it with a backslash. it's a way to say to perl "hey this is not the actual end of string, this is a character I want to be in the string"

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#DEFINE AN ARRAY
my @names = ("Andrew","Andy","Kaufman");


$names[1] = "\"$names[1]\"";
print "@names";
```

This will modify the array too.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having any of the arrays in double quotes?

Comment: I'm not following. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Create an array with the values “Andrew,” “Andy,” and “Kaufman” (without the quotes). Write a program that prints Andrew "Andy" Kaufman. I'm trying to get this for an assignment and I thought it meant without any double quotes.